# Copy files using Windows explorer

Tags: 2010, 2016

we are going to move document library files from SP 2010 to SP 2016. Both are in the same domain.

We need to move all files with permissions and the last two versions.

Will opening both document library using Windows explorer move the permissions and versions as well?

What's the best approach to move files with versions and permissions in SharePoint without using third party tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a migration tool. Sharegate happens to be my personal favorite, but other vendors like Metalogix (Quest?), AvePoint, and others create these tools, as well. Or you have to script it yourself, probably not worth the effort you'd need to go through.

No, using Explorer will not copy any of that information.

Comment: Thank you Trevor, could you share any ready scripts to move files with permissions and versions?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, sorry.